# Are there different sets of PhpStorm inspection rules, for example for different versions of PHP?

Tags: phpstorm, code-analysis

I am totally new to PhpStorm.  I imported some existing code via "New Project from Existing Files", and set up a scope to ignore some third party libraries, *.bak files, and such.  I also went into File / Settings / Languages & Frameworks / PHP, and set the "PHP language level" for the current project to 5.3 (which is unfortunately the appropriate level for the server where the production code will be running).

Then I did an "Inspect Code".  A bunch of warnings came up.  This is expected, as I had never used PhpStorm before.  I clicked on some of them more or less randomly, and this caught my eye:

> Function mysql_error is deprecated.

Function mysql_error is *not* deprecated.  Well, I mean, it is, of course, but it is deprecated *as of version 5.5 of PHP*.  I am using an earlier version of PHP, and I thought that I had explained that fact to PhpStorm (via the "PHP language level" setting).

Maybe I can get rid of mysql_error even in PHP 5.3, I don't know yet, but this is just an example.  My main concern is that it seems likely that there will be a billion inspection warnings that are due to issues like this - i.e. due to the fact that the inspection engine seems to think I have access to a higher version of PHP than I actually do.  Is there a way to specify a different ruleset, appropriate to the version of PHP that I'm using?

Comment: What is your PhpStorm version? Please try [v11 EAP builds](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/02/phpstorm-11-eap-144-3656/) -- it has some improvements in stubs versioning (not sure if this particular moment is already implemented though). In any case: the possible solution right now could be to just disable "deprecated" inspection, especially if you checking against old version of PHP.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne.  My version is 10.0.3, which is the version that the main download link on JetBrains gave me this morning.